# How do I use CDPATH to cd to Documents no matter which directory I am in?

Tags: command-line, bash, cd-command

If the cd shell builtin doesn't see the target directory in the current directory, it consults CDPATH. If the target directory is absolute (begins with the root directory, /), CDPATH is not used.

CDPATH is a colon-separated list of directories, e.g.

```
CDPATH="/home/walt/first:/usr/local/bin:/home/walt"
```

I could then `cd  Documents`, no matter what my current directory happens to be.

How can I `cd Documents` no matter what my current directory ? I have tried cd Documents on not my current directory and it gives an error message.

If the cd shell builtin doesn't see the target directory in the current directory, it consults CDPATH

How can it consults CDPATH? If the cd shell builtin doesn't see the target directory in the current directory It gives an error.

I’m just saying if I cd into photos folder for example ,from any other directory than my home directory,it gives an error message,right?

Comment: Please [edit] with the terminal output including the commands run and the error messages, because we are having a hard time reproducing the problem. Btw putting bin there is useless. Your 4th paragraph apparently contradicts your 5th paragraph.

Comment: "it gives an error message,right" No, it shouldn't. I get a message saying `/home/$USER/Pictures` then a prompt showing me in that directory. Are you sure the directories exist? You can also run that `CDPATH=` line right before you run your `cd` command in case you didn't add it to your .bashrc properly

Comment: When `CDPATH` is set, the current directory will not be searched unless it’s in that `CDPATH` i.e. make sure `.` is in that path at the beginning (which seems to not be the case in yours) So, add it by prepending `.:` to `CDPATH` … Is that what you’re asking?

Comment: @Raffa `CDPATH="/home/$USER/first:/usr/local/bin:/home/$USER"; cd /; cd Downloads; cd some_other_folder_in_downloads` works fine even without the `.`

Comment: It consults CDPATH?  I’m confusing this

Comment: @DanielT It shouldn’t unless you’re actually in one of those directory paths already … So go to some other directory path not listed there and try.

Comment: @GuilhermeWoolley i.e. it uses `CDPATH` to search for the bare (not absolute path) directory name passed as argument instead of the normal searching PWD but only if `CDPATH` is set AFAIK

Comment: I have to use the  CDPATH command? Because I can’t cd directly form any other directory?

Comment: @Raffa How could a `/bin/cd` exist? All external binaries (without `exec`) are run by forking a subprocess. No matter where the subprocess changes its cwd to, the shell parent process will not be affected

Comment: If the cd shell builtin doesn't see the target directory in the current directory, it consults CDPATH,It means it only consults? Because if I cd  into a directory and the target directory is not on my current directory there’s an error

Comment: @DanielT I got that one mixed ... You are right on `cd` exists only as a shell builtin ... But, if `CDPATH` is set, you still can't `cd` to a directory in PWD if it exists with the same name somewhere else that is listed in `CDPATH` AFAIK

Comment: @DanielT However it seems my info is a bit outdated even on that :-)

Comment: @DanielT some systems have an executable `cd`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50058/70524 (thankfully not Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Let's go over an example:

#### Setup

```
root@daniel-tablet1:~# adduser walt
info: Adding user `walt' ...
info: Selecting UID/GID from range 1000 to 59999 ...
info: Adding new group `walt' (1004) ...
info: Adding new user `walt' (1004) with group `walt (1004)' ...
info: Creating home directory `/home/walt' ...
info: Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
New password: 
Retype new password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
Changing the user information for walt
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
        Full Name []: 
        Room Number []: 
        Work Phone []: 
        Home Phone []: 
        Other []: 
Is the information correct? [Y/n] 
info: Adding new user `walt' to supplemental / extra groups `users' ...
info: Adding user `walt' to group `users' ...
root@daniel-tablet1:~# runuser walt
walt@daniel-tablet1:/root$ cd ~
walt@daniel-tablet1:~$ mkdir -p first Documents/first photos/second
walt@daniel-tablet1:~$ find
.
./.face
./.profile
./.bash_logout
./.config
./.config/korgacrc
./.bashrc
./Documents
./Documents/first
./.face.icon
./photos
./photos/second
./first
```

---

> I have tried cd Documents on not my current directory and it gives an error message..

Before you set `CDPATH`, it is empty. Normally you can't cd to the directory from anywhere.

```
walt@daniel-tablet1:~/Documents$ echo $CDPATH # Not set

walt@daniel-tablet1:~$ cd Documents # Works from its parent directory
walt@daniel-tablet1:~/Documents$ cd /usr
walt@daniel-tablet1:/usr$ cd Documents # Doesn't work elsewhere
bash: cd: Documents: No such file or directory
```

If you want your changes to `CDPATH=` to persist and be loaded into every shell you open in your user, put the line at the end of your `~/.bashrc` and reboot.

> I could then cd Documents, no matter what my current directory happens to be.

```
walt@daniel-tablet1:/usr$ CDPATH="/home/walt/first:/usr/local/bin:/home/walt"
walt@daniel-tablet1:/usr$ cd Documents
/home/walt/Documents
```

> If the cd shell builtin doesn't see the target directory in the current directory, it consults CDPATH

No, it consults CDPATH first, then checks the current directory for the target directory. As @Raffa said: "But, if CDPATH is set, you still can't cd to a directory in PWD if it exists with the same name somewhere else that is listed in CDPATH AFAIK".

```
walt@daniel-tablet1:~/Documents$ ls # There is a directory named "first" here
first
walt@daniel-tablet1:~/Documents$ cd first # But `cd`ing it sends us somewhere else according to CDPATH
/home/walt/first
```

> I’m just saying if I cd into photos folder for example ,from any other directory than my home directory,it gives an error message,right?

No? I can't imagine which error message you are getting.

```
walt@daniel-tablet1:~/first$ echo $CDPATH # Check the value
/home/walt/first:/usr/local/bin:/home/walt
walt@daniel-tablet1:~/first$ cd photos/ # I can go to photos from anywhere
/home/walt/photos
walt@daniel-tablet1:~/photos$ mkdir second # If I make a directory name that doesn't collide
walt@daniel-tablet1:~/photos$ cd second # I can go there as expected unlike with `first`
walt@daniel-tablet1:~/photos/second$ cd /usr # Go to "any other directory than my home directory"
walt@daniel-tablet1:/usr$ cd photos # Will succeed without error message 
/home/walt/photos
walt@daniel-tablet1:~/photos$
```